# CSS3 animation issue with z-index

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions

I have two elements in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ztv/). Each expands on mouseover with a `:hover` transition.

I want the blue animation to match the red one. Right now the red one expands over top of the blue one on mouseover, but the blue one expands *under* the red one. I would like each to animate *over top of* the other. This could probably be done by changing the z-index on `:hover` but that didn't seem to work very well.

Comment: ?? -- for me, it does exactly what you want ..

Comment: What browser are you using? I know in IE that z-index only works on positioned elements if the parent has a higher z-index.

Comment: I am using chrome 13, but I see the glitch in firefox 6 as well. I want the animation to be smooth all of the way accross.

Comment: This is not a question, it's somebody asking for somebody else to do their homework for them. Sorry, I'm very forgiving about stack overflow rules but this "question" just doesn't belong here *at all*.

Comment: Your jsfiddle has gone 404. Any chance you still have a copy of it somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are animating all properties, the z-index animates and steps from 0 to 1 *at the end of the animation*.

Just animate the properties that you need and it works:

```
#a, #b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/hfM7E/

Comment: I like your solution, but what if I want to animate more than one property other than `z-index` such as height? Would I comma-separate the values? It doesn't seem to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/hfM7E/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the CSS (and remove the `z-index` modifier in `#a:hover, #b:hover {...}`):

```
#a {
    background: #55a;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#b:hover {
    z-index: 2;   
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h6ztv/3/

Comment: The jsfiddle link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting initial z-index value to '0'

```css
#a, #b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    z-index:0;
    }

#a:hover, #b:hover {
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```